# Tallit Katan Length Question

Tags: tallit-katan, size

I have a size 22 and I want to order one that tucks better into my pants. Right now the tzizit are tucked in but the garment itself doesn't reach my pants. Do I buy a bigger sized tallit katan (like a 24 or a 26) or do I need to look for some other measurement? I'm happy with the width of the garment, I would just like it to be longer on the front and back.